# Move Visual Studio 2010 Project from one TFS to another?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a project in visual studio 2010 bind to the TFS. Now we have a new TFS server, i'd like to move my entire project to new TFS server. But here is the problem. I have lots of pending changes that i made while i was offline. So as you can imagine i do not want to lose any pending changes but i have to bind my current project to the new TFS server?

And also i cannot check-in my old data because the old TFS server that my project is bind is currently unavailable.

I cannot shelve my changes because i cannot go online with the old TFS.

How could i manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep any TFS history then you'll need to migrate the project across.

Otherwise, just forget the old server and add the files to your new server:

- Back up your data
- In File > Source Control, Unbind the project (or just Clean it and get rid of all .scc/.vssscc files etc)
- Move the source code into an approriate place in your (new) workspace folder, or map the current location into your new workspace, so that the project is in a source-controlled location for your new server.
- Go to Source Control and Add all the solution files to the new source control
- Check in

Answer (score 0):

- Check in all old data
- Migrate using TFS migration to the new Server

otherwise you may lose data

Comment: I cannot check-in my changes because the old TFS server is currently unavailable. If i could though, there would be no problem.

Comment: If the old server is not available, you need to just remove the server bindings as suggested by Jason [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9664742/267), and rebind to the new server. You won't be able to migrate the history of the project (which is on the server which you said was unavailable.)